# How to make a title for this multi-axis matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This function:

```
def plotGrid(ax, grid, text=''):
  ax.imshow(grid, cmap=cmap, norm=Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=9))
  ax.grid(True, which='both', color='lightgrey', linewidth=0.5)  
  ax.set_yticks([x-0.5 for x in range(1+len(grid))])
  ax.set_xticks([x-0.5 for x in range(1+len(grid[0]))])   
  ax.set_xticklabels([])
  ax.set_yticklabels([])
  ax.set_title(text)
  

def plotTaskGrids(task):
  nTrain = len(task['train'])
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, nTrain, figsize=(3*nTrain, 3*2))

  for i in range(nTrain):   
    plotGrid(ax[0, i], task['train'][i]['input'], 'train input')
    plotGrid(ax[1, i], task['train'][i]['output'], 'train output')

  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.title('title')
  plt.show()
```

displays this window:

[image]

I would like to replace `Figure 1` in the window title with `title`, but `plt.title('title')` doesn't accomplish that, instead it changes one of the subtitles. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try adding num="title" when calling plt.subplots?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, nTrain, figsize=(3*nTrain, 3*2), num="title")
```

This should get passed to the plt.figure call within the subplots call.

Comment: Thank you, it works. It wasn't easy to find the documentation for `num=` parameter, but I found it here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure